# Como consertar erro de acentuação do CMD?

Tags: cmd

Estou com problema para mostrar mensagens no `cmd` pois as mesmas quando acentuadas aparecem desfiguradas. Isso ocorre em qualquer linguagem que eu use (C, C++, .bat, etc).

Por exemplo em vez de :

```
minha multiplicação é :
```

Aparece :

```
Minha multiplica├º├úo ├® :
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de consertar isso com alguma configuração específica do Windows para o `cmd`.

Obs.: Uso o Windows 8. Configurar com chcp 1252 não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Você disse que a mensagem aparece desfigurada. Poderia editar a pergunta mostrando a maneira com que a mensagem aparece?

Comment: Pergunta editada.

Comment: O texto original aparenta estar em UTF-8, chcp 1252 não é UTF-8.

Comment: `chcp 860` funciona?

Comment: @VictorStafusa todos esses encodings "antigos" são single-byte. Para UTF-8, se contorna com o 65001, mas o caminho melhor no meu ver é mudar o encoding dos fontes na IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Antes de mais nada:** o problema me parece no seu código, e não no CMD.

Se vai fazer aplicações para o console, o caminho mais prático é mudar a codificação na sua IDE/editor de texto para uma compatível com o OS de destino, em vez de usar UTF.

Sua string está em UTF-8. Neste caso você deve usar:

```
chcp 65001
```

É de se esperar que o encoding 1252 não funcione para o seu caso.

Comment: É isso. chcp 65001.

Comment: @Beto Boa noite, considere aceitar a resposta. Visto que resolveu!

Answer (score -2):

Pra mim resolveu colocando CHCP 1252 e salvando com codificação ANSI.

[image: Cabeçalho do código da aplicação]

[image: Modo de salvar o arquivo]

[image: Execução do script com acentuação funcionando!]